# How to make this hair not pass through the arms/shoulder on rigging character

Tags: mesh, armature

I want to animated this character and i'm using wiggle plugin to make hair auto animated but the hair is passing through the arm, and i want to make the hair not to pass trough the arm.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is wiggle plugin? it sounds really useful.

Comment: u can read this https://blenderartists.org/t/wiggle-bones-a-jiggle-bone-implementation-for-2-8/1154726 @Millard